# Unable to configure RSA server private key

Tags: apache, ssl

I don't understand what's happen on my server. Just bellow the ssl_error_log

```
[Sat Sep 30 00:51:07 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.website.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Sat Sep 30 01:33:05 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `website.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Sat Sep 30 01:33:05 2017] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Sat Sep 30 01:33:05 2017] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

I don't understand why the check was done on www.website.com and now on website.com...

I'm not a expert on web but I want to understand this problem. Which information I have to look?

Best regards, 
robin

Comment: This looks like a SSL/TLS handshake error where a request came through with "www.website.com" as the common name (CN). This also usually means that the private key that is being loaded in the VirtualHost section of your .conf file doesn't match the SSL Certificate being loaded in the same section. See [Troubleshooting Apache SSL Certificate Errors](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-fix-common-ssl-errors.htm)

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now